# Invoke-RESTMethod error "request_data must be of type: dict"

Tags: powershell, rest

I am just starting out with REST API and the only language I have available to me is PowerShell

I am calling a list of "things" - this works and I get the ID property

I then try to iterate through that list and get a more detailed record for the "thing" (The second Invoke-RestMethod) - when I attempt this I get an error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"reply": {"err_code": 500, "err_msg": "Got an invalid input while processing XDR public API", "err_extra": "request_data must be of type: dict"}}

I thought that convertto-json would convert the hashtable "request" to a dictionary.

I am new to this so please don't assume I know anything.

```
$ContentType = "application/json"
$URL_All = 'https://api-<company>.xdr.eu.paloaltonetworks.com/public_api/v1/endpoints/get_endpoints/'
$URLEndpoint = 'https://api-<company>.xdr.eu.paloaltonetworks.com/public_api/v1/endpoints/get_endpoint/'

$endpoints = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $URL_All -method POST -Headers @{"x-xdr-auth-id" = "1"; "Authorization" = "<API-KEY_Goes_Here>" } -ContentType "application/json" -Verbose
if ($endpoints.reply.count -gt 0){
    write-host "Found $($endpoints.reply.count) details"
}
else {
    write-host " API didn't return any endpoint - ending script "
    break
}
foreach ($endpoint in $endpoints.reply) {
    if($endpoint.agent_id -ne $null){
    $request = @{
        request_data = '{}'
        filters      = @{
            field       = "endpoint_id_list"
            operator    = "in"
            Value       = "$($endpoint.agent_ID)"
            Search_from = 0
            Search_to   = 1
            sort        = @{ 
                field   = "last_seen"
                keyword = "desc"
            }
        } 
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    $Endpoint_full += Invoke-RestMethod -uri $URLEndpoint -method POST -Body $request -Headers @{"x-xdr-auth-id" = "1"; "Authorization" = "<API-KEY_Goes_Here>" } -ContentType "application/json" -Verbose
    }
}
```

Comment: @iRon Always worth a look, in this case it converts to Json and back without issue using the default depth of 2 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON conversion isn't the issue, the hint is in the error message.

```
"request_data must be of type: dict"
```

Key being `request_data` which just consists of this in your request:

```
request_data = '{}'
```

Ie. it's basically blank while the API expects a hash table or similar structure.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had indeed put the contents of request_data in the wrong place. The line below that produces the hash table named "Filters" should have been inside the request_data table. It has resolved this error and delivered another ... apparently Filters needs to be of type "list" ... Ive marked your reply as the answer because it solved the original query.